# Verifying a "forced" edit

Tags: feature-request

If my post gets edited by another user (with low rep) afaik I can verify that edit or this is done by 1 or more reviewers.

To my understanding users with high rep can edit questions directly without a second instance. I am okay with that, I haven't seen a bad edit there and most of the time I want to verify that the edit is in my favor.

So the question is:

Would it make sense to give the author the possibility to verify or "reject" forced edits. 
A verify would signal that the author approves of the edit and the "rejection" would bring the edit into the review queue so it can be judged by someone else.

edit: I don't want to change the system as it is now, I like that.

So to address the possible duplicate:
I thought of this as a optional approval after everything has taken place. So maybe when I revisit SO 2 days later and I see my post was edited I may just verify that this is in my favor (the "rejection"-feature may be discarded). Still a rejection would be better then a roll-back because it just gets reviewed and the editor is not provoked until a neutral decision was made.

Comment: You can rollback the edit anyway if you feel it doesn't fit to your question/answer.

Comment: If you mean trusted edits *should not be committed* until they receive owner approval, well, that changes... everything. Everything about the nature of Stack Overflow Q&A.

Comment: @BoltClock That is exactly what I not meant. It is about the 'possibility' to give edits "certificate of approval". Which happens after the normal process.

Comment: It seems that I was not clear about the process. Shall I close this question, reformulate it and post a new one that is hopefully clearer?

Comment: @KamiKaze You shouldn't delete and re-post; you should edit (as you've just done). Note that the downvotes don't mean that the question itself is bad. On Meta, downvotes are also used to express disagreement. People disagree with the feature request.

Comment: I downvoted because I don't really see how more content needs to end up in review queues; community editing works exceptionally well in several ways, and one of the ways is that bad edits get corrected by others; either through further edits or through rollbacks. The goal is to get content into a good shape quickly, what is proposed here just slows things down - potentially a lot. For what exact purpose, I don't really see yet.

Comment: I don't get your proposal at all - assuming review queue works correctly why do you expect your rejection of community decision on the edit (approve) to be accepted? Indeed if you roll the die enough times you get the number you like... but why would you do that if you allowed to pick outcome yourself?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov My initial thought was that the author could just "verify" an edit, to show that he is okay with it or that he liked it. The other part with the rejection came to mind afterwards, so that a "forced" edit could be reviewed under these circumstances. The review would be binding though. I thought of this as a possibility for explicit feedback of the author without disturbing the normal process. Mainly because I wanted to show that I am fine with the edit. I learned 2 things, though. 1 I should have been more verbose on the process. 2 The idea was not good^^

Answer (score 3):

Considering that the post owner is already given a binding vote when reviewing suggested edits on their posts, the equivalent for edits that have already been committed is simply to roll them back if you deem them inappropriate. Allowing edits that have already been committed to be punted back to a review queue adds a completely needless layer of complexity to the revision system when these edits can simply be either rolled back, or edited over.

Answer (score 1):

This would be possible, but it would have a drawback. It would mean that people who edited your question, would now have to wait for your approval (or rejection).

This opens a few other issues. What about edits to posts by users who are no longer around? Would these edits have to linger forever? Or should we automatically pass them after, say, 2 days?

So, if you disagree with an edit by a user with full edit privileges - just go to the edit history and roll back to a previous revision.

Comment: This is not what I meant. The OP could optionally give his statement to the edit, but as it is not mandatory it is not required for anything.

Comment: @KamiKaze So if I understand it right, you want to apply the edit immediately. Then the OP could Reject it, which would send it to the review queue (where it might be Approved after all). I don't really see an advantage here - a rollback will get rid of the edit too. And I'd rather not add more to the review queue, for a variety of reasons.